# Deflate and Gzip not working in Htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, compression

I have set deflate in htaccess but its not working. Mod deflate is enable on server.
Here is my code of htaccess:

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
DeflateCompressionLevel 1
</ifModule>
```

Comment: How do you know it's not working?

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to check if mod_defalte.c is running.

e.g.

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
Redirect 302 / https://www.google.com/
</ifmodule>
```

Then go and load your website and see if you are getting redirecting google or not.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have allowoverrides enabled in Apache config (httpd.conf etc)

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#allowoverride

If not, then no htaccess config will have any effect